# Logic to check if exact ids (3+ records) are present in a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some sample data like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
    ([FK_ID], [TYPE_ID])
VALUES
    (10, 1),
    (11, 1), (11, 2),    
    (12, 1), (12, 2), (12, 3),
    (14, 1), (14, 2), (14, 3), (14, 4),
    (15, 1), (15, 2), (15, 4)
```

Now, here I am trying to check if in each group by `FK_ID` we have exact match of TYPE_ID values for `1, 2 & 3`.

So, the expected output is like:

1. `(10, 1)` this should fail

   - As in group `FK_ID = 10` we only have one record
2. `(11, 1), (11, 2)` this should also fail

   - As in group `FK_ID = 11` we have two records.
3. `(12, 1), (12, 2), (12, 3)` this should pass

   - As in group `FK_ID = 12` we have two records.
   - And all the `TYPE_ID` are exactly matching `1, 2 & 3` values.
4. `(14, 1), (14, 2), (14, 3), (14, 4)` this should also fail

   - As we have 4 records here.
5. `(15, 1), (15, 2), (15, 4)` this should also fail

   - Even though we have three records, it should fail as the `TYPE_ID` here (1, 2, 4) are not matching with required match (1, 2, 3).

Here is my attempt:

```
select * from mytable t1
where exists (select COUNT(t2.TYPE_ID) 
          from mytable t2 where t2.FK_ID = t1.FK_ID
          and t2.TYPE_ID IN (1, 2, 3)
          group by t2.FK_ID having COUNT(t2.TYPE_ID) = 3);
```

This is not working as expected, because it also pass for `FK_ID = 14` which has four records.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14fdc/2/0)

Also, how we can make it generic so that if we need to check for 4 or more `TYPE_ID` values like (1,2,3,4) or (1,2,3,4,5), we can do that easily by updating few values.

Comment: Please describe the output you want.

Comment: I just need the records with `FK_ID = 12` as that only match the requirement as mentioned in #3

Answer (score 3):

The following query will do what you want:

```
select fk_id
from t
group by fk_id
having sum(case when type_id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 3 and
       sum(case when type_id not in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This assumes that you have no duplicate pairs (although depending on how you want to handle duplicates, it might be as easy as using, `from (select distinct * from t) t`).

As for "genericness", you need to update the `in` lists and the `3`.

If you want something more generic:

```
with vals as (
      select id
      from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(id)
     )
select fk_id
from t
group by fk_id
having sum(case when type_id in (select id from vals) then 1 else 0 end) = (select count(*) from vals) and
       sum(case when type_id not in (select id from vals) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Won't this also succeed on: `(10,1),(10,2),(10,1)`?

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis . . . I addressed this by saying no duplicates (originally).  I edited the answer to explain what to do if there are duplicates.

Comment: If you use `from (select distinct * from t) t` it will also match `(10,1),(10,2),(10,3),(10,1)`

Comment: Could you add `and count(distinct type_id) = 3` to the having clause?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
SELECT y.fk_id FROM
    (SELECT x.fk_id, COUNT(x.type_id) AS count, SUM(x.type_id) AS sum 
    FROM mytable x GROUP BY (x.fk_id)) AS y
WHERE y.count = 3 AND y.sum = 6
```

For making it generic, you can equal y.count with `N` and y.sum with `N*(N-1)/2`, where `N` is the number you are looking for `(1, 2, ..., N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.  `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` used for eliminate duplicate records.

```
SELECT 
    [FK_ID]
FROM 
    @mytable T 
GROUP BY 
    [FK_ID]
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [TYPE_ID] IN (1,2,3) THEN [TYPE_ID] END) = 3
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN [TYPE_ID] NOT IN (1,2,3) THEN [TYPE_ID] END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select FK_ID,count(distinct TYPE_ID) from mytable
 where TYPE_ID<=3
 group by FK_ID
 having count(distinct TYPE_ID)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CTE` with `Dynamic` pass Value which you have mentioned in Q.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT FK_ID,
            COUNT(*) CNT
     FROM #mytable
     GROUP BY FK_ID
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 3) <----- Pass Value here What you want to Display Result,
     CTE1
     AS (
     SELECT T.[ID],
            T.[FK_ID],
            T.[TYPE_ID],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.[FK_ID] ORDER BY
                             (
                                 SELECT NULL
                             )) RN
     FROM #mytable T
          INNER JOIN CTE C ON C.FK_ID = T.FK_ID),
     CTE2
     AS (
     SELECT C1.FK_ID
     FROM CTE1 C1
     GROUP BY C1.FK_ID
     HAVING SUM(C1.TYPE_ID) = SUM(C1.RN))
     SELECT TT1.*
     FROM CTE2 C2
          INNER JOIN #mytable TT1 ON TT1.FK_ID = C2.FK_ID;
```

From above `SQL` Command which will produce Result (I have passed `3`) :

```
ID  FK_ID   TYPE_ID
4   12      1
5   12      2
6   12      3
```